# Linux commands to copy one file to many files

Tags: linux, cp

Is there a one-line command/script to copy one file to many files on Linux?

```
cp file1 file2 file3
```

copies the first two files into the third. Is there a way to copy the first file into the rest?

Comment: A question is do you want file2 and file3 to occupy independent blocks or not?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Does

```
cp file1 file2 ; cp file1 file3
```

count as a "one-line command/script"? How about

```
for file in file2 file3 ; do cp file1 "$file" ; done
```

?

Or, for a slightly looser sense of "copy":

```
tee <file1 file2 file3 >/dev/null
```

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Yeah, but since the OP clearly wants this to work for more than just two destination files, I went with the form that highlights the support for that. Maybe I should have written `tee <file1 >file2 file3 file4` and dispensed with the two-file parallelism?

Comment: Not sure if this is still relevant, but I just want to note that using the tee solution, would not preserve the initial files rights.

Comment: @bioShark: Right -- it only copies the contents of the files. That's why I described it as "a slightly looser sense of 'copy'".

Comment: just for fun, if you need a big list of files `tee <sourcefile.jpg targetfiles{01-50}.jpg >/dev/null`

Answer (score 14):

> just for fun, if you need a big list of files:
>
> `tee <sourcefile.jpg targetfiles{01-50}.jpg >/dev/null`- [Kelvin Feb 12 at 19:52](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550540/linux-commands-to-copy-one-file-to-many-files?newreg=e84e4ff6c4a4413590913c6f8b041e19#comment58448148_9550556)

But there's a little typo. Should be:

> `tee <sourcefile.jpg targetfiles{01..50}.jpg >/dev/null`

And as mentioned above, that doesn't copy permissions.

Answer (score 9):

You can improve/simplify the `for` approach (answered by @ruakh) of copying by using **ranges** from **bash brace expansion**:

```
for f in file{1..10}; do cp file $f; done
```

This copies `file` into `file1, file2, ..., file10`.

Resource to check:

- http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace#ranges

Answer (score 4):

*(no loops used)*

To copy the content of one file *(fileA.txt)* to many files (*fileB.txt, fileC.txt, fileD.txt)* in Linux,

use the following combination **cat** and **tee** commands:

```
cat fileA.txt | tee fileB.txt fileC.txt fileD.txt >/dev/null
```

- applicable to any file extensions
- only file names and extensions change, everything else remains same.

Answer (score 3):

```
for FILE in "file2" "file3"; do cp file1 $FILE; done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `shift`:

```
file=$1
shift
for dest in "$@" ; do
    cp -r $file $dest
done
```

Comment: What is the effect of `shift`?

Answer (score 2):

`cat file1 | tee file2 | tee file3 | tee file4 | tee file5 >/dev/null`

Comment: It probably works, but its is pretty inflexible.  And it will likely be inefficient if you are copying large files.

Comment: @StephenC it's a lot closer to the original query though

Comment: If you use cat and tee, might as well: cat file1 | tee file2 file3 file4 >/dev/null

Answer (score 1):

Use something like the following. It works on zsh.

> cat file > firstCopy > secondCopy > thirdCopy

or

> cat file > {1..100} - for filenames with numbers.

It's good for small files.

You should use the cp script mentioned earlier for larger files.

Comment: It assumes the shell is `zsh`

Comment: Why does the size of the files matter? Limited by RAM size?

Comment: Because of the cat processing

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend creating a general use script and a function (**empty-files**), based on the script, to empty any number of target files.

Name the script **copy-from-one-to-many** and put it in your PATH.

```
#!/bin/bash -e
#  _ _____     
# | |___ /_  __  
# | | |_ \ \/ /  Lex Sheehan (l3x)
# | |___) >  <   https://github.com/l3x
# |_|____/_/\_\  
#
# Copy the contents of one file to many other files.

source=$1
shift
for dest in "$@"; do
    cp $source $dest
done

exit
```

## NOTES

The `shift` above removes the first element (the source file path) from the list of arguments (`"$@"`).

### Examples of how to empty many files:

#### Create file1, file2, file3, file4 and file5 with content:

```
for f in file{1..5}; do echo $f > "$f"; done
```

#### Empty many files:

```
copy-from-one-to-many /dev/null file1 file2 file3 file4 file5
```

#### Empty many files easier:

```
# Create files with content again
for f in file{1..5}; do echo $f > "$f"; done 

copy-from-one-to-many /dev/null file{1..5}
```

## Create empty_files function based on copy-from-one-to-many

```
function empty-files()
{
    copy-from-one-to-many /dev/null "$@"
}
```

### Example usage

```
# Create files with content again
for f in file{1..5}; do echo $f > "$f"; done 
# Show contents of one of the files
echo -e "file3:\n $(cat file3)"

empty_files file{1..5}
# Show that the selected file no longer has contents
echo -e "file3:\n $(cat file3)"
```

> Don't just steal code. Improve it; Document it with examples and share it. - l3x

---

Here's a version that will preface each cp command with **sudo**:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
# Filename: copy-from-one-to-may
#  _ _____     
# | |___ /_  __  
# | | |_ \ \/ /  Lex Sheehan (l3x)
# | |___) >  <   https://github.com/l3x
# |_|____/_/\_\  
#
# Copy the contents of one file to many other files.
# Pass --sudo if you want each cp to be perfomed with sudo
# Ex: copy-from-one-to-many $(mktemp) /tmp/a /tmp/b /tmp/c --sudo

if [[ "$*" == *--sudo* ]]; then
    maybe_use_sudo=sudo
fi

source=$1
shift
for dest in "$@"; do
    if [ $dest != '--sudo' ]; then
      $maybe_use_sudo cp $source $dest
    fi
done

exit
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest/quickest solution I can think of is a for loop:

```
for target in file2 file3 do; cp file1 "$target"; done
```

A dirty hack would be the following (I strongly advise against it, and only works in bash anyway):

```
eval 'cp file1 '{file2,file3}';'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard scripting commands for that instead:

Bash:

```
 for i in file2 file3 ; do cp file1 $i ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Go with the **fastest** cp operations

```
seq 1 10 | xargs -P 0 -I xxx cp file file-xxx
```

it means

- `seq 1 10` count from 1 to 10
- `|` pipe it `xargs`
- `-P 0` do it in parallel - as many as needed
- `-I xxx` name of each input `xargs` receives
- `cp file file-xxx` means copy file to file-1, file-2, etc

and if name of files are different here is the other solutions.
**First** have the list of files which are going to be created. e.g.

```
one
two
three
four
five
```

**Second** save this list on disk and read the list with `xargs` just like before but without using `seq`.

```
xargs -P 0 -I xxx cp file xxx  < list
```

which means 5 copy operations in parallel:

```
cp file one  
cp file two  
cp file three  
cp file four  
cp file five
```

and for `xargs` here is the behind the scene (**5 forks**)

```
 3833 pts/0    Ss     0:00 bash
15954 pts/0           0:00  \_ xargs -P 0 -I xxx cp file xxx < list
15955 pts/0           0:00      \_ cp file one
15956 pts/0           0:00      \_ cp file two
15957 pts/0           0:00      \_ cp file three
15958 pts/0           0:00      \_ cp file four
15959 pts/0           0:00      \_ cp file five
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how correct this is but i have used something like this

```
echo ./file1.txt ./file2.txt ./file3.txt | xargs -n 1 cp file.txt
```

Where `echo ./file1.txt ...` is destination of a file and use it to feed `xargs` with one "destination" by one. Therefore command `xargs -n 1`. And lastly `cp file.txt`, which is self explanatory i think :)