# copy files to multiple directories at once

Tags: linux, shell, unix, cp

```
mkdir dir{0..99}
echo hello > file
```

**I want to copy `file` to every directories, `dir0` to `dir99`.**

Currently, the best solution I came up with is:

```
for i in {0..99}; do cp file dir$i; done
```

but there must be much more elegant ways to do this.

*Is there a way to `cp` a file to multiple directories using a command similar to below?*

```
cp file dir*
cp file dir{0..99}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux commands to copy one file to many files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550540/linux-commands-to-copy-one-file-to-many-files). I think it should, since there is a nice solution using tee that can be easily adapted to your case: `tee dir{0..99}/file <file`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xargs` to call `cp` 100 times :

```
echo dir{0..99} | xargs -n 1 cp file
```

check the man of `xargs`